# Confluence: user macros in templates

Tags: confluence

[I wrote a user macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100213/confluence-copy-to-clipboard-button) for Confluence 5.10.8 which renders a non-editable textfield together with a copy button. It has a parameter called `Text` which is defined like this

```
## @param Text:title=Text|type=string|required=true|desc=The text to be displayed and copied
```

Now I want to use this macro in a template which has a variable `$foo`. How can I use that variable as part of my user macro parameter `Text`? Referencing it with `$foo` in the parameter looks exactly like in the preview (see screenshot below), i.e. it renders “$foo” instead of its value.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is not possible to use template variables in macro parameters. In the end I removed the parameter and am now using template variables in the **body** instead. Body processing has to be set to *Rendered*. I am not sure why, but it did not work with the other options (Escaped, Unrendered).

**Macro example**

[image]

**Template example**

[image]